# align main content with custom view in actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

The designer wants that the main content is aligned with ( one element ) in the custom-view in the ActionBar. But I have yet found no way to measure the distance between the left most of the custom-view to the bezel ( means width of icon + affordance ) in the Actionbar.
Anyone knows a way to determine that size?

[image]

Comment: As good as you may have described the problem, there are a lot of non-english speakers on SO, so adding some code or an image figure may help others help you.

Comment: In general you are right, but I don't know which part of the code would help to make this particular question clearer.

Comment: In this case; screenshot of what you have vs picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: just added an image - hope this makes things clearer